# Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent from Elmah

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

here is my OnActionExecuting.
i know this question old but there was no luck for me with the previous answers that were given to similar question on stackoverflow.
thought of sharing my method.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
            if (session.IsNewSession || SessionHelper.GetUserData() == null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Error(ValidationMessages.SessionExpired);
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new JsonResult{Data = new{Error = AppConstants.SessionTimeout,LogOnUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl},JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
                }
                else
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new{controller = "Account",action = "Login",area = "",returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url}));
                }
            }
        }
```

the issue is when user is in any of the pages that contains grids and grid buttons. and when user session expired then if user clicks on grid buttons . then the following error is occurred.
have tried to set

```
Response.BufferOutput = true;
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
```

before the filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
line but no luck
can any one help on this please.